# Recursive Variance

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, bayesian

What will be the distribution or features about the following $x$?

$x=\mu+\epsilon$

where $\epsilon\sim N(0,x^{-1})$.

It seems interesting in econometrics if we allow $x$ being a time series and $x_t\sim N(\mu,x_{t-1}^{-1})$ which is called autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity. But what if we cancel $t$ and make it purely recursive?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this actually defines a distribution.

Comment: I'm not either.  @Jian How would you sample a single observation from this distribution?

Comment: I am working on a fixed point proposition and suddenly all the proofs go to this step. I cannot think a way out. I am trying to separate the $x^{-1}$ out of the variance but it seems not possible.

Comment: You might want to try posting the part of your argument that leads here to see if there's a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Your time series must have an initial condition or starting point. What is that? Also is the second argument of $N$ the variance or the SD? Also $\mu$ must be large enough to prevent negative $x$'s for all practical purposes. Any information about that?

Answer (score 0):

With trial answers to some of the questions in my own comment, suppose we begin the time series at $t = 1$ with $X_1 = \mu = 50$ and that the SD of the normal distribution is $1/X_{t-1}$.

Then the iteration seems to converge quickly to $Norm(\mu = 50,\; \sigma = 1/\mu = 1/50).$  Similarly for $\mu=5$. A According to a Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test the simulated data are
consistent with a normal distribution with these parameters.
The first 5000 simulated observations are also consistent with a normal distribution
according to a Shapiro-Wilk test. A plot of autocorrelations
shows no significant autocorrelations up to lag 40.

If my choices are at all realistic in your situation, it seems to me that the univariate
version of this idea must be simply $X \sim Norm(\mu, 1/\mu).$

Below is a simulation in R (ACF plot not shown):

```
 mu = 50;  m = 10^4;  x = numeric(m);  x[1] = mu
 for(t in 2:m) x[t] = rnorm(1, mu, 1/abs(x[t-1]))
 mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 49.99985
 ## 0.02007789

 ks.test(x, pnorm, mu, 1/mu)

 One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:  data:  x 
 D = 0.0082, p-value = 0.5055      # consistent with NORM(50, 1/50)
 alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 shapiro.test(x[1:5000])

 Shapiro-Wilk normality test:  data:  x[1:5000] 
 W = 0.9996, p-value = 0.4416      # consistent with normal
```

[image]